# Use directory in docker-compose.yml's parent folder as volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── alice
├── docker
│   ├── compose-prod.yml
│   ├── compose-stage.yml
│   ├── compose.yml
│   └── dockerfiles
├── gauntlet
├── nexus
│   ├── Procfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── VERSION.txt
│   ├── alembic
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── app
│   ├── poetry.lock
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   └── scripts
```

`nexus.Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --group app
WORKDIR /usr/src/pdn/nexus

COPY ../../nexus/pyproject.toml ../../nexus/poetry.lock* ./

ARG INSTALL_DEV=true
RUN bash -c "if [ $INSTALL_DEV == 'true' ] ; then poetry install --no-root ; else poetry install --no-root --no-dev ; fi"

COPY ../../nexus .

RUN chmod +x scripts/run.sh
ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/pdn/nexus
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME
USER app

CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

The relevant service in `compose.yml` looks like this:

```
services:
  nexus:
    platform: linux/arm64
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/dockerfiles/nexus.Dockerfile

    container_name: nexus
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ../nexus:/usr/src/pdn/nexus:ro
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOSTNAME=${DATABASE_HOSTNAME?}
    env_file:
      - .env
```

When I run compose up, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./scripts/run.sh": permission denied: unknown
```

The service starts ok without the volume definition. I think it might be because of the the location of `nexus` in relation to the dockerfile or compose file, but the context is set to the parent.

I tried defining the volume as follows:

```
volumes:
      - ./nexus:/usr/src/pdn/nexus:ro
```

But I get a similar error, in this case `run.sh` is not found: and a directory named `nexus` gets created in the `docker` directory

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./run.sh": stat ./run.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You're overwriting the entire contents of your image with a `volumes:` mount, and that can cause all kinds of problems like this if your host directory doesn't happen to exactly match what the image builds (for example, the effects of the `RUN chmod +x` line are hidden).  You shouldn't normally need to hide the image's contents like this; can you delete the `volumes:` block?

Comment: @DavidMaze I see what you mean. I could delete the volume, but ideally I'd like to keep it for hot-reloading during development. I suppose the other option would be to make the directory structures match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've two comments, not sure if they can solve your issue.

**First** although, in your compose.yml,  your are allowed to reference your parent directories, that not the case in your Dockerfile, you can't copy from outside the context which you specified in your compose.yml file (.. which resolve to your app root). So you should change those lines:

```
COPY ../../nexus/pyproject.toml ../../nexus/poetry.lock* ./
COPY ../../nexus .
```

to

```
COPY ./nexus/pyproject.toml ./nexus/poetry.lock* ./
COPY ./nexus .
```

**Second** the volume overrides whatever in /usr/src/pdn/nexus by the content of ../nexus. This will render your whole copies, to /usr/src/pdn/nexus, useless. That may not be an issue if the contents are the same, but whatever permission you defined in your files may be gone. So if your contents are the same, the only issue you may have is your starting script, you can put it into a separate directory out of the /usr/src/pdn/nexus so that it won't be overridden, and don't forget to reference it correctly into the CMD.

Comment: This [repo](https://github.com/m-azzain/odoo-dev-env) may give some insights